# extension according platform Premake

Tags: premake

I have a premake file that handles a bunch of Matlab/Mex functions and static librarys. One project per matlab's function and one project per static library.

I'm using four platforms

```
platforms { "Win32", "Win64","Linux32","Linux64" }
```

I need that in the Win32 and Linux32 platforms the extension of the matlab's functions (targetextension) be ".mexglx" and in the "Win64" and "Linux64" platforms the extension (targetextension) be ".mexa64".  But I don't want that extension in the  library projects.

I think that I'm need to use rules but I couldn't figure out how to use it.

It's run with

```
if os.is64bit() then
    extension = ".mexa64"
else
    extension = ".mexglx"
end
...
project "foo"
    kind "ConsoleApp"
    language "C++"
    files { "foo.cpp" }
    targetextension(extension)
```

but it's clearly awful

Comment: I didn't mention that I'm using Premake 5

Comment: no need to write these `if`s, use `configuration 'Win32' targetextension ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
filter { "platforms:*32", "kind:not StaticLib" }
   targetextension ".mexglx"

filter { "platforms:*64", "kind:not StaticLib" }
   targetextension ".mexa64"
```